# How can a TIFF file be centered properly in a PDF file with the DIN A4 format?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, tiff

The following program converts a TIF file to PDF file using itext-library (Version 2.1.7).

```
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.PageSize;
import com.lowagie.text.Image;
import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Tiff2Pdf {

    public static File convert(String tifPath, String pdfPath) {
        File pdfFile = null;
        String imgeFilename = tifPath;
        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(
                    document,
                    new FileOutputStream(pdfPath));
            writer.setStrictImageSequence(true);
            Image image;
            document.open();
            RandomAccessFileOrArray ra = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(imgeFilename);
            int pagesTif = TiffImage.getNumberOfPages(ra);
            for (int i = 1; i <= pagesTif; i++) {
                image = TiffImage.getTiffImage(ra, i);
                image.scaleAbsolute(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getHeight());
                Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(633, 842);
                document.setPageSize(pageSize);
                document.newPage();
                document.add(image);
            }
            pdfFile = new File(pdfPath);
            document.close();
            PdfReader read = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //do nothing
        }
        return pdfFile;
    }
}
```

But the PDF file is not aligned centered.

How can the converted TIF file be aligned centrally in PDF file?

Comment: iText 2.1.7 dates from 2009. TIFF support improved dramatically in the last few years. Don't complain if you don't upgrade and some TIFF cause a problem. Also: reading your code, only your first page will be A4, the other pages will be slightly bigger due to your `setPageSize()`. Finally, you're using `scaleAbsolute()` instead of `scaleToFit()`, which means you don't have to center the TIFF to make it fit, you're stretching the page to match A4 (but you're page size isn't A4).

Comment: The higher version from iText library is chargeable.

Comment: The old version can cost you more: http://lowagie.com/itext2

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.PageSize;
import com.lowagie.text.Image;
import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

/**
 *
 * @author Rahman
 */
public class Tiff2Pdf {

    public static File convert(String tif, String pdf) {
        File pdfFile = null;
        String imgeFilename = tif;
        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(
                    document,
                    new FileOutputStream(pdf));
            writer.setStrictImageSequence(true);
            Image image;
            document.open();
            RandomAccessFileOrArray ra = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(imgeFilename);
            int pagesTif = TiffImage.getNumberOfPages(ra);
            for (int i = 1; i <= pagesTif; i++) {
                image = TiffImage.getTiffImage(ra, i);
                image.scaleAbsolute(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getHeight());
                document.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                document.newPage();
                document.add(image);
            }
            pdfFile = new File(pdf);
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //do nothing
        }
        return pdfFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can even drop `document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);` because your page size is already A4 (A4 is the default page size when you create the `Document` object without passing any parameters).